# Dropdown menu is not displayed even though it works on other pages with almost same CSS

Tags: html, css

Since I am quite new to HTML and CSS, I still have a lot of issues. One thing I'm struggling with atm is my dropdown menu. On my other pages, it works. However, on my homepage, it won't show up. I've compared both my CSS of the "Pottery" and "Tutorial" page - which is quite similar - but I can't find the mistake... I know that my code is still very confused, this is because I'm still learning and this is my first project, so bear with me ;)

This is my other page with the dropdown menu (once I hover over "Pottery" it appears): [image]

[image]

Maybe someone knows a solution for this problem. Thank you in advance :)

Here's my code:

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: Baskerville, Helvetica, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .2em;
  background-image: url(file:///Users/alinasprenger/Documents/FH%20St.%20Po%CC%88lten/Interaktive%20Medien/Images/Pottery_Website_Background.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  color: #A5A58D;
    }
    
.header1{
  height: 90px;
  padding: 80px 0;
  font-size: 68px;
  letter-spacing: 12px;
  text-transform:   uppercase;
    }

nav{
  background: #B7B7A4;
  font-size: 36px;
  height: 49px;
  width: 100%;
}

nav a {
  font-size: 36px;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav.categoryContainer ul, nav.categoryContainer li{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

ul{
  background: #B7B7A4;
  height: 49px;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  width: 25%;
  position: relative;
}

li a{
  display: block;
  line-height: 49px;
  padding: 0 1em;
  color: #FFF1E6;
}

li a:hover, .category > li:hover > a{
  background: #AEAE98;
  height: 49px;
  position: relative;
}

.current, a:hover.current{
  background: #909072;
  color: #FFF1E6;
  position: relative;
  height: 49px;
  cursor: default;
}

ul.dropdown{
  float: none;
  background: #FFF1E6;
  color: #B7B7A4;
  width: 125%%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  left: -9000em;
  z-index: 5;
  padding-right: 0%;
}

ul.dropdown li{
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.category li:hover ul{
  left: 0;
}

.categoryContainer > ul > li:hover > .dropdown {
  left:0;
}

ul.dropdown li a{
  color: #B7B7A4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #B7B7A4;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul.dropdown li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
} 

ul.dropdown li a:hover{
  background: #FFE8D6;
}

.header2{
      display: flex;
      height: 90px;
      width: 100%;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      font-size: 50px;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 20%;
    }
    
.text1{
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 35px;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 15%;
    }
    
    .footerContainer {
      bottom: 3%;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
    
    }

    .footer{
      width: 50%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #A5A58D;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-right: 1px solid #A5A58D;
      padding: 0 20px;

}

.footer2{
      font-size: 25px;
      color: #A5A58D;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en"> 


<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="WS 2020 Screendesign.css">

<title> ALINA'S POTTERY </title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header1"> Alina's Pottery </div>
  
  <nav class="categoryContainer">
  <ul>
    <li class="current"><a href="home.html" title="Home" class="category">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="pottery.html" title="Pottery" class="category">Pottery</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="general.html" title="General" class="subCategory">General</a></li>
            <li><a href="handbuilding.html" title="Hand-Building" class="subCategory">Hand-Building</a></li>
            <li><a href="potterywheel.html" title="Pottery Wheel" class="subCategory">Pottery Wheel</a></li>
            <li><a href="materials.html" title="Materials" class="subCategory">Materials</a></li>
            <li><a href="temperatures.html" title="Temperatures" class="subCategory">Temperatures</a></li>
        </ul>   
        </li>

        <li><a href="tutorials.html" title="Tutorials" class="category">Tutorials</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="viewall.html" title="View All" class="subCategory">View All</a></li>
                <li><a href="getstarted.html" title="Get Started" class="subCategory">Get Started</a></li>
                <li><a href="plates.html" title="Plates" class="subCategory">Plates</a></li>
                <li><a href="mugs.html" title="Mugs" class="subCategory">Mugs</a></li>
                <li><a href="bowls.html" title="Bowls" class="subCategory">Bowls</a></li>
            </ul>   
            </li>
        <li><a href="shop.html" title="Shop" class="category">Shop</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>

<div class="header2"> Welcome to my pottery portfolio! </div>
  
<div class="text1"> I am very passionate about creating my own ceramics. </div>

<section class="footerContainer">
    <a href="aboutme.html" title="About Me" class="footer">About Me</a>
    <a href="socials.html" title="Socials" class="footer"> Socials</a>
    <a href="imprint.html" title="Imprint" class="footer2">Imprint</a> 
</section>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Alina I have fixed your code. It was so weird and there are some extra lines of code and many well-written lines of code but you don't fully understand CSS yet that's why you are making these little mistakes you can check the code I have explained every change in comment. Here's your code:

```css
* {
  /*Used to select every element in the document*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
  /*Dont use overflow hidden when not needed*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
  font-family: Baskerville, Helvetica, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  
  background-image: url("https://images.alphacoders.com/597/597503.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  color: #a5a58d;
}

.header1 {
  height: 90px;
  padding: 80px 0px;
  font-size: 68px;
  letter-spacing: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav {
  background: #b7b7a4;
  font-size: 36px;
  height: 49px;
  width: 100%;
}

nav a {
  font-size: 36px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav.categoryContainer ul,
nav.categoryContainer li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

ul {
  background: #B7B7A4;
  height: 49px;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  width: 25%;
  /* position: relative; */
}

li a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 49px;
  padding: 0 1em;
  color: #fff1e6;
}

li a:hover,
.category > li:hover > a {
  background: #aeae98;
  height: 49px;
  position: relative;
}

.current,.current:hover{
  background: #909072;
  color: #fff1e6;
  cursor: default;
}

ul.dropdown {
  /* float: none; */
  background: #fff1e6;
  color: #b7b7a4;
  width: 125%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  /* left: -9000em; */
  /* Dont use left property here instead use display here */
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-right: 0%;
}

ul.dropdown li {
    /* float: none; */
    width: 100%;
}

/* .category:hover ul.dropdown {
    display: none;
    left: 0;
} */

.categoryContainer > ul > li:hover > .dropdown {
    display: block;
    /* left: 0; */
}

ul.dropdown li a {
  color: #b7b7a4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b7a4;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul.dropdown li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul.dropdown li a:hover {
  background: #ffe8d6;
}

.header2 {
  display: flex;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20%;
}

.text1 {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 35px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15%;
}

.footerContainer {
  bottom: 3%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #a5a58d;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #a5a58d;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.footer2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #a5a58d;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

Comment: wow thank you sooo much! I know, it was very messed up... this project for me is just trial and error to be honest ... :) thanks again! this helps a lot

Comment: @alinas haha no problem I am also a beginner still struggling to get my websites to work. please gimme like if you can so that my reputation may increase

Comment: sure thing :) I just ran into one more problem (maybe you know the solution to this): when I hover over the dropdown menu items, the box they're sitting in shrinks in size and therefore the one that I am hovering over gets smaller. I'm going to post it in the question so you can see what I mean :)

Comment: @alinas, Yea I saw that and didn't try fixing it but now sure I will try

Answer (score 0):

So Alina,
The dropdown sizing problem is solved and every change is explained in comments:

```css
* {
  /*Used to select every element in the document*/
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
  /*Dont use overflow hidden when not needed*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
  font-family: Baskerville, Helvetica, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  
  background-image: url("https://images.alphacoders.com/597/597503.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  color: #a5a58d;
}

.header1 {
  height: 90px;
  padding: 80px 0px;
  font-size: 68px;
  letter-spacing: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav {
  background: #b7b7a4;
  font-size: 36px;
  height: 49px;
  width: 100%;
}

nav a {
  font-size: 36px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav.categoryContainer ul,
nav.categoryContainer li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

ul {
  background: #B7B7A4;
  height: 49px;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  width: 25%;
  /* position: relative; */
}

li a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 49px;
  padding: 0 1em;
  color: #fff1e6;
}

li a:hover,
.category > li:hover > a {
  background: #aeae98;
  height: 49px;
  position: relative;
}

.current,.current:hover{
  background: #909072;
  color: #fff1e6;
  cursor: default;
}

ul.dropdown {
  /* float: none; */
  background: #fff1e6;
  color: #b7b7a4;
  width: 125%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  /* left: -9000em; */
  /* Dont use left property here instead use display here */
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-right: 0%;
}

ul.dropdown li {
    /* float: none; */
    width: 100%;
}

/* .category:hover ul.dropdown {
    display: none;
    left: 0;
} */

.categoryContainer > ul > li:hover > .dropdown {
    display: block;
    /* left: 0; */
}

/* So the bug was here you should style anchor text only for font color and stuff related to font atleast in this situation */
/* ul.dropdown li a{ 
  color: #b7b7a4;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b7a4;
  white-space: nowrap;
} */
/* you should write it like */
ul.dropdown li{ 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b7b7a4;
}
ul.dropdown li a{ 
    color: #b7b7a4;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul.dropdown li:last-child {
   /* You can also write it like this.It will keep border's space but not color. It's usefull many times*/
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; */
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul.dropdown li a:hover {
  background: #ffe8d6;
}

.header2 {
  display: flex;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20%;
}

.text1 {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 35px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15%;
}

.footerContainer {
  bottom: 3%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #a5a58d;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #a5a58d;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.footer2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #a5a58d;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```